# Rails: change configuration loaded from YAML at runtime in unit/functional tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Suppose you have a similar YAML configuration file:

```
defaults: &defaults
  # registration form
  birth_date: true
  address: true
  zip: true
  city: true
  state: true
  # other stuff
  send_email_notification_to_users: true

production:
  <<: *defaults

development:
  <<: *defaults

test:
  <<: *defaults
```

which is loaded in a similar way to how it is explained in Railcast #85:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file

Suppose you need to test how the application performs with different settings, how would you do that?

With Django it is possible to change the settings temporarily during unit tests:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#overriding-settings

Is it possible to do something similar with Rails?

Comment: I guess you store settings in a hash? change the hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you implemented it exactly like it is explained in Railscast #85, simply assign the new value like so:

```
APP_CONFIG['perform_authentication'] = false
# or
APP_CONFIG['my_fancy_key'] = 'my fancy value'
```

Keep in mind that the value will not be changed back automatically after your test case finished, so it will remain valid for all subsequent test cases.

Comment: sorry it took me a long time to come back here but in the end I tested the solution and it works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

change the configurations dynamically, using maybe before and after blocks:

```
before(:all) do 
  @old_config = APP_CONFIG
  APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/config.yml")["production"]
end
after(:all) do
  APP_CONFIG = @old_config
end
```

Comment: i didn't know about these before and after methods, where can i find more information about it?

Comment: sorry, I assumed you were testing with rspec: http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-rails/file/README.md . If you are using TestUnit, just do your asserts in between the two blocks (and of course skip the before/afters)